# Node.JS: Converting tcp to stdin/stdout

Tags: networking, node.js, process, stdin, isolation

Node.JS seems limited in its ability to live-update code and in its ability to automatically isolate exceptions. Both of which are practically by default in Java.

One very effective way to live-update is to have a listener process that simply echos communication to/from the child process. Then to update, the listener starts up a new child (which reads the updated code automatically) and then starts sending requests to the new child,, ending the old child when all requests are complete.

- Is there already a system that provides this http functionality through stdout/stdin.
- Is there a system that provides TCP server or UDP server functionaility through stdout/stdin.

By this I mean, providing a module that looks like the `http` or `net` module with the exception that it uses stdout/stdin for the underlying I/O.

Similar to [This CGI module](http://brianmckenna.org/blog/nodejs_via_cgi)

> some applications will only have to change `require('http')` to `require('cgi')`

I intend to do something similar. I hope to re-use code if it is already out there, and also to easily convert a small or single purpose webserver, into this listener layer which runs many webapps. It is important that cleanup occurs properly. Connections that end or error should be freed up and the end/error events/commands should be properly echoed both ways.

(I believe a common way is to have the children listen on ports and the parent communicate with those ports, but I think an stdout/stdin solution will be more efficient)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/) ([HttpUpstreamModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUpstreamModule)) or [HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/). In both cases you'd run them in front and mark a backend as down and then bring it back up when you need to do a live upgrade.

Comment: I will consider it but I am not sure whether it will fit well in our structure. It will of course need to support multiple backends that each have their own control over specific domains/paths.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain that this is what you're looking for (indeed, I'm not certain that I understand your question), but Remy Sharp has written a very helpful node module called [nodemon](http://github.com/remy/nodemon). It promises to "monitor for any changes in your node.js application and automatically restart the server." This may help with the issue of live updating code.